# Custom form implementation with Spring-Boot 3 and Spring-Security 6 in Java 17

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I would like to implement a "custom form" for authentication with Spring-Security and I'm having difficulty with the various documentations, as I'm creating a project in Java 17 with Spring-Boot 3 and Spring-Security 6, below is my class configuration:

**SecurityConfig**

```
package com.raf.config;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import com.raf.model.Utente;
import com.raf.repository.UtenteRepository;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{
    
    @Autowired
    private UtenteRepository utenteRepository;
    
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().permitAll())
            .formLogin(login->login
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/elencoStudenti")
                .permitAll())
            
            .logout(logout-> logout.permitAll());
            
        return http.build();
    }
    

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        
        List<Utente> listUsers=this.utenteRepository.findByRoles("USER");
        List<Utente> listAdmin=this.utenteRepository.findByRoles("ADMIN");  
        List<UserDetails> users= new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
        
        for(Utente u: listUsers) {
            UserDetails user = User.builder()
                    .username(u.getUsername())
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode(u.getPassword()))
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();
            users.add(user);
        }
        
        for(Utente u: listAdmin) {
        UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username(u.getUsername())
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode(u.getPassword()))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        users.add(admin);
        }
        
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(users);
    }
    
}
```

the foreach loops collect the account information from the database and store it in an arrayList, and this procedure works fine, my only problem is the redirection to my hypothetical custom login page (.jsp or html) placed in "main/webapp/WEB -INF/viev"

here is my controller which for now performs 2 simple functions (entering students and printing the list), one of the 2 methods is accessible only from the ADMIN account (entering)

**@ControllerStudenti**

```
package com.raf.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import com.raf.model.Studente;
import com.raf.repository.StudenteRepository;

@Controller
public class ControllerStudenti {
    
    @Autowired
    private StudenteRepository studenteRepository;
    
    @GetMapping(path="/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping(path="/inserisciStudenti")
    public String inserisciStudenti(Model m) {
        
        Studente studente1=new Studente();
        studente1.setId(1);
        studente1.setNome("raffaele");
        studente1.setCognome("tammaro");
        
        Studente studente2=new Studente();
        studente2.setId(2);
        studente2.setNome("antonino");
        studente2.setCognome("cannavacciuolo");
        
        this.studenteRepository.save(studente1);
        this.studenteRepository.save(studente2);
        List<Studente>listaStudenti=this.studenteRepository.findAll();
        
        m.addAttribute("studenti",listaStudenti);
        
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path="/")
    public String home(Model m){
        List<Studente> listaStudenti=this.studenteRepository.findAll();
        m.addAttribute("studenti",listaStudenti);
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path="/elencoStudenti")
    public String elencoStudenti(Model m){
        List<Studente> listaStudenti=this.studenteRepository.findAll();
        m.addAttribute("studenti",listaStudenti);
        return "index";
    }
    

    
}
```

All this code works correctly with the standard functions already provided by spring security (default login-page and logout).
Please help me!

Comment: Show request and response with headers, Show your Spring Security TRACE logs.